# How to find out the price an app was purchased at?

Tags: iphone

I will make one of my app one day free.
Is there an api or any parameter that can know if the user's app is the purchased copy or the copy with free charge?

Welcome any comment

Comment: Interesting question, you should rephrase it, so it gets more attention. Like "How to find out if an App was purchased for free".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way of knowing the price at which the user has purchased the app. So, answering your question, you have no way of knowing if an application has been purchased or downloaded for free.

Answer (score 0):

do you want the app to behave differently if downloaded on the free day? Maybe you could store the date of first launch, and compare that to some web service you develop that returns an array of those days you made the app free. If the users first use date was among those, assume it was a free download (obviously it's not exact because they could have downloaded and not used until a future date)...

if you just want to know, you could add a call to your server on first use and store that data so you'd have a record...but it's still dependent on date, not literally price

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

You could do it like this: eg. store off a NSUserDefault with the version. 
Then make the next version for free, dont forget to increment version.

If no previous entry of a version is in NSUserDefault then you could flag another NSUserDefault, eg. FreeApp with 1.

Then in the next version you put on you will put the price active again. Now you can check if FreeApp was 0 or 1 when reding the NSUserDefault, if it was 1 then those are the ones that updated that got the version for free.

Unfortunately when the app gets deleted so does the NSUserDefault of it and a redownload of it, even when being paid would be free but your app will store it off as paid.

Hope this makes sense.